# Google play services - Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection

Tags: google-play-services

After generated signed APK file and use this file to directly install to real device, it works well. But when use exactly this file to upload to Play Store I got that error.
(My App's already published)

Answer (score 0):

If you use gradle to compile your APK, check if your version is newer than the previous published one on Play Store.

in **build.gradle**

```
{
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I checked. Version code is always greater than previous on play store.